# Dynamically allocated objects in main() Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, object, dynamic

I have a couple dynamically allocated objects in my `int main()`, how should I delete these at the end of the program? Currently I think i'm not freeing the memory at the end of the program, here's the main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow *w = new MainWindow;
    breadData *dat = new breadData("audit.dat");
    //link main window with bread data
    w->_link(dat);
    //show main window
    w->show();
    //execute loop
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: In practice, you don't have to. Often in QT programs they don't. But it gives me the willies so I try to avoid that pattern (either make concrete instances of the objects or use smart pointers).

Comment: @MadScienceDreams You don't have to free memory after object owned by other object (parent-child relationship). In OP's code there's no such relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow *w = new MainWindow;
    breadData *dat = new breadData("audit.dat");
    //link main window with bread data
    w->_link(dat);
    //show main window
    w->show();
    //execute loop
    int result = a.exec();
    delete dat;
    delete w;
    return result;
}
```

but dynamic allocation looks pretty unnecessary.
Why not

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    breadData dat("audit.dat");
    //link main window with bread data
    w._link(&dat);
    //show main window
    w.show();
    //execute loop
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: dynamic allocation does actually seem pretty arbitrary now that I think about it. Thanks for that second snippet

Answer (score 2):

You're correct, right now you're leaking an instance of `MainWindow` and an instance of `breadData`.

For `QObject` instances, the simplest thing to do is to use the built-in memory management. Make your `QObject`s owned by `QApplication` and they'll be deleted at the time `QApplication` is destructed.

For other objects, use smart pointers - like you should be, anyway!

```c++
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget g; // dummy, just to demonstrate ownership - will delete children
               // upon leaving the scope
    // 1. For QObjects/QWidgets
    // 1a. use QObject/QWidget ownership
    MainWindow *w = new MainWindow(&g);
    // 1b. or use a smart pointer
    QScopedPointer<MainWindow> w(new MainWindow);
    // 2. For any other class: use smart pointers
    QScopedPointer<breadData> dat(new breadData("audit.dat"));
    //link main window with bread data
    w->_link(dat);
    //show main window
    w->show();
    //execute loop
    return a.exec();
}
```

BTW, that `breadData` constructor better be throwing an exception when the reading of the file or parsing of it fails. Otherwise you get an "invalid" object, and good luck ensuring that the rest of the application knows how to deal with that.